# How to use Matlab's 512 element lookup table array in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, lookup-tables, image-morphology

I am designing morphological operations in OpenCV. I am trying to mimic the functions `remove` and `bridge` in Matlab's bwmorph. To do this I referred to the function definition of bwmorph.m, there I obtained the Look up table arrays for remove and bridge.

After that step the procedure is same for both Matlab and OpenCV.

```
      lut(img,lutarray,img)
```

Problem is that Matlab uses a 512 element (9bit) look up table scheme while OpenCV uses a 256 element (8bit) look up scheme, how do I use the Matlab lutarray in OpenCV?

After doing some research I came across [this post](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=5629924).

What does the person mean when they're saying that they "split" the image from 0-512 and then into two parts?

Is the above method even correct? Are there any alternates to doing this?

Comment: No one? I think the person meant that he was applying the operations on thr first (0-255) and second  (256-511) halves of a histogram of size 512 bins (??), but then again this is conjecture on my part, I may be completely off track with this.


Tried contacting that person (sonmi) but it goes directly to the mailing list @yahoogroups .

Can anyone help me with this? How do I use a Matlab lutarray in openCV for binary images?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your own posts here. We hope that everyone with a good question gets an answer, but since 99% of folks here are volunteers, we cannot guarantee it.

Comment: `bwlookup(BW,lut)` or `applylut` performs a 2-by-2 or 3-by-3 nonlinear neighborhood filtering operation on binary or grayscale image BW, where as `cv::LUT` is a per pixel lookup table operation. So yes, you could split the image to perform the latter but the first mentioned, the `bw = applylut(bw, lut)` in bwmorph.m cannot be replicated using `cv::LUT` or other stock OpenCV function.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read somewhere that the OpenCV library uses the 8 elements around a pixel as the values for the look up table. Am I right on this? I seem to remember seeing a diagram somewhere but now cant find it. Would you know in which order the bits are taken from around a pixel value?

Comment: There isn't. `cv::LUT` is not a neighborhood operation, but B(x,y) <- LUT[ A(x,y) ] for all (x,y). You can mimic `bwmorph`s remove by image minus erosion by star shape kernel. Bridge takes a little more effort.

Comment: Actually tried that. I can model remove by findcontours + drawcontours in OpenCV. But I still need to model a few more morphological operations like bridge etc.

I was referring to how the LUT operation is applied to OpenCV, I read somewhere that the eight elements surrounding an object are taken converted to a decimal which is looked for in a LUT, after which the value at the position in the LUT given by the decimal is the output.

If the above is wrong, How does the LUT work in OpenCV? contd.....

Comment: contd from above.  

By now, I've damn well memorized the google search results for most permutations of "How the look up table works in OpenCV", so far nothing. Even in their own docs, there is a portion of how to scan images. It explains nothing about the lut function itself. Tried looking for into the definition of the lut function(its code), could not quite understand what was happening. 

So any books or links which can explain how the LUT in OpenCV works would be great.

Comment: Might be worth using handles to ping people here, OP (cc @mainactual).

Comment: @halfer well if it gives you any closure, I was the one who upvoted your comment about not vandalizing my own post. I thought it was pretty good advice.

Comment: @user6334139: alright, thanks. I hope you can get the answer you're after here - I don't know this domain space, but the below answer looks good.

Comment: @halfer sorry if you felt I ignored you. I felt that if I replied you might think that I was arguing with you, which is not my intention at all. But thanks for cleaning the post and all that you did.

Answer (score 3):

`bwlookup(bw,lut)`

http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlookup.html

or internally, `applylut` both perform a 2-by-2 or 3-by-3 neighborhood operation on a binary (black & white) image, whereas OpenCV's `cv::LUT` performs a per pixel gray level transform (closely related to `intlut` in MATLAB). An example of latter is performing a gamma correction on gray level image.

```
//! transforms array of numbers using a lookup table: dst(i)=lut(src(i))
CV_EXPORTS_W void LUT(InputArray src, InputArray lut, OutputArray dst,
                  int interpolation=0);
```

To my knowledge, there is no neighborhood `bwlookup` implementation in OpenCV. However, following the description of MATLAB's `bwlookup`, you can write it yourself.

```
// performs 3-by-3 lookup on binary image
void bwlookup( 
    const cv::Mat & in, 
    cv::Mat & out, 
    const cv::Mat & lut,
    int bordertype=cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 
    cv::Scalar px = cv::Scalar(0) ) 
{
    if ( in.type() != CV_8UC1 )
        CV_Error(CV_StsError, "er");
    if ( lut.type() != CV_8UC1 || lut.rows*lut.cols!=512 || !lut.isContinuous() )
        CV_Error(CV_StsError, "lut size != 512" );
    if ( out.type() != in.type() || out.size() != in.size() )
        out = cv::Mat( in.size(), in.type() );

    const unsigned char * _lut = lut.data;
    cv::Mat t;
    cv::copyMakeBorder( in,t,1,1,1,1,bordertype,px);
    const int rows=in.rows+1;
    const int cols=in.cols+1;
    for ( int y=1;y<rows;++y)
    {
        for ( int x=1;x<cols;++x)
        {
            int L = 0;
            const int jmax=y+1;
#if 0 // row-major order
            for ( int j=y-1, k=1; j<=jmax; ++j, k<<=3 )
            {
                const unsigned char * p = t.ptr<unsigned char>(j) + x-1;
                for ( unsigned int u=0;u<3;++u )
                {
                    if ( p[u] )
                        L += (k<<u);
#else // column-major order (MATLAB)
            for ( int j=y-1, k=1; j<=jmax; ++j, k<<=1 )
            {
                const unsigned char * p = t.ptr<unsigned char>(j) + x-1;
                for ( unsigned int u=0;u<3;++u )
                {
                    if ( p[u] )
                        L += (k<<3*u);
#endif
                }
            }
            out.at<unsigned char>(y-1,x-1)=_lut[ L ];
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it against `remove` and `bridge` so should work. Hope that helps.

Edit: After checking against a random lookup table,

```
lut = uint8( rand(512,1)>0.5 ); % @MATLAB
B = bwlookup( A, lut );
```

I flipped the order the indices appear in the lookup table (doesn't matter if the operation is symmetric).

Comment: Hello @mainactual,

Thank you very much for your response. I wanted to ask you, how did you implement the morphological operations? I just tried this thing for the lutarray for remove on a binary image and all I get is a black screen.

Comment: @user6334139, you can multiply `lut` array (1 & 0) by the desired output value (0xFF typically) so the output will follow. Or alternatively rescale `out`. I guess it's hard to diminish 1s on the screen. I just saved MATLAB's lookup table in png and imported it that way.

Comment: Okay got it working! Will test it with a few more morphological operations and let you know. In the meanwhile, can you tell me your interpretation of the code? What is going on in it?

Comment: @user6334139, it makes a pattern of the 3-by-3 neighborhood by setting bits [0:8] on/off according to their position in the neighborhood. Afterwards, any such morphological operation becomes O(1) lookup.

Comment: Hello,
I checked the implementation and it gives a result. The same result for both remove and bridge and for any other LUTarray operation. I looked at results for both of them in matlab and they dont match the result at all.

I'm looking at octave's definition of bwmorph.m  

      kernel = - conndef (ndims (bw), "minimal");
      kernel(ceil (numel (kernel) /2)) = nnz (kernel) -1;
      morph = @(x) convn (x, kernel, "same") > 0;

Comment: The kernel (for any single channel binary image) is a matrix similar to the one mentioned in the post in OpenCV-users consisting of powers of 2. The last line seems to be the problem. I use filter2D for it but the result is what looks like Octave's implementation of bridge. I feel I'm missing out on the "same" feature in filter2D and " > 0" which I've modeled as thresholding greater than zero, am I right in doing this?

Comment: @user6334139, you don't have to buy it, it's open source. However, it's not a matter of opinion, so I invite you to run the cross-validation code https://github.com/mainactual/bwlookup . This applies to MATLAB, I have no idea about the octave.

Comment: @mainactual I tested the code against the lookup tables provided in MATLAB for the skeletonization approach and didn't give the same result as MATLAB. For skeletonization there are 8 LUTs that are executed repeatedly until the pixels in the binary image do not change anymore. I am checking where the bug might have occurred but please let me know if you take a look at it. Great work btw :)

Comment: @MMahdiChamseddine, nice that you like :) I checked the MATLAB circles.png: all 8 luts exported as `uint8( images.internal.lutskel(i) )` in total 100 iterations (should converge by then) and logic copied from `algbwmorph` as you said. Make sure not to force the function in-place (must be `input.data!=output.data`) and use the algorithm from github. My results were identical.

Comment: @mainactual oddly enough when I tried the algorithm on a different day it worked. I might have changed something without documenting it and thus I am not able to know what caused the problem in the first place. thank you for your reply and sorry for the late response.