# Image Segmentation - Remove Unwanted Pixels in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm working on image processing. Firstly, I have to make image segmentation and extract only boundary of image. Then, This image is converted to freeman chain code. The part of freeman chain code is Okay. But, When I make a segmentation of image, inside of the image remains some unwanted white pixels. And thus, the next step,which is freeman chain code, is not being succesfull. I mean, It gives incorrect chain code because of unwanted pixels. So, I have to remove unwanted pixels from inside of image. I will share my code and can you tell me how i can change in this code or what kind of a correct code can i should write for this filter ? Code is here :

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Mat img = imread("<image-path>");
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat binary;
    threshold(gray,binary, 200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat kernel = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
            1, 1, 1,
            1, -8, 1,
            1, 1, 1);
    Mat imgLaplacian;
    Mat sharp= binary;
    filter2D(binary, imgLaplacian, CV_32F, kernel);
    binary.convertTo(sharp, CV_32F);
    Mat imgResult = sharp - imgLaplacian;
    imgResult.convertTo(imgResult, CV_8UC1);
    imgLaplacian.convertTo(imgLaplacian, CV_8UC1);
    //Find contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector <uchar> chaincode;
    vector <char> relative;
    findContours(imgLaplacian,contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size();i++){
        chain_freeman(contours[i],chaincode);
        FileStorage fs("<file-path>", 1);
        fs << "chain" << chaincode;
    }
    for (size_t i=0; i<chaincode.size()-1; i++){
        int relative1 = 0;
        relative1 = abs(chaincode[i]-chaincode[i+1]);
        cout << relative1;
        for (int j=0; j<relative1; j++){
        }
        relative.push_back(relative1);
            FileStorage fs("<file-path>", 1);
            fs << "chain" << relative;
        }


    imshow("binary",imgLaplacian);
    cvWaitKey();
        return 0;
}
```

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcSFZ.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9odLo.jpg)

In this result, I want to remove white pixel inside of the image. I tried all fiter in opencv but I could not achieve. It's very important because of chain code.

Comment: Isn't `cv::findContours` already given you a list of contours, where size of each describes the length of the contour? If it is an 8-connected outside of a single pixel, it consists of four elements. Or just morph close or use connected component labeling to fill holes beforehand.

Comment: I tried it but It didn't work or I couldn't work it. I used morph close but the resulting is still same.

Comment: Maybe you could post image you wish to achieve? But use `cv::findContours` for the binary image right after the threshold, you don't need edge detector here.

Comment: @mainactual Okay , I edited on my post. You can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I see it. As said, you can ignore small contours simply by their length. For the rest, you need maximally thin contours (seems like 4-connected is the case). There you have couple options:

1) thinning of the current. If you can grab Matlab's lookup table, you can then load it into OpenCV as [How to use Matlab's 512 element lookup table array in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226853/how-to-use-matlabs-512-element-lookup-table-array-in-opencv/37584827)

2) it's pretty simple to label the boundary pixels by hand after binarization. To make it more efficient, you can first fill small cavities (islets) by applying connected component labeling on the background (using opposite connectivity this time, 8 it is).

2i & 2ii) If you do the labeling by hand, you can either continue collecting the contour vector by hand or switch to `cv::findContours`

Hope this helps